# How run cmd in java program as administrator?

Tags: java

pleeas help me 
how can i run cmd in my java App as Administrator

I was able to extend my forward a bit but it was to ask me a password and there is no place to put a password

This picture shows

the picture :

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
```

public class CMD {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /user:Administrator cmd");

        BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String l;
        while((l=BR.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.print(l);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: plz add post your code along with the question and not the screenshot.

Comment: Try to write admin password in the console and press ENTER

Comment: Code is add in post now

Comment: Try running eclipse as an administrator

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to execute

```
runas /profile /user:Administrator /savecred
```

In this scenario you will need to provide password once and in future jvm will not prompt you for password. You can provide password directly on the command window/eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the handle of the process, use the InputStream of the process to read the password prompt and the OutputStream to write the password along with a "\r\n" to simulate entering the password on the console.